SQL query not working for respective output
Below is my query,
I have also attached the expected out out and current query result output.
How can I update the query to get the expected result?
select
    bookings.id as departure,
    return_detail .id as return_id
from
    bookings
left join bookings return_detail on
    bookings.trip_id = return_detail .trip_id
left join booking_passengers bp on
    bookings.id = bp.bp_booking_id
left join booking_passengers return_bp on
    return_detail .id = return_bp .bp_booking_id
where
    bp.bp_passenger_id = 31
    and return_bp .bp_passenger_id = 31
    --and bp.id != return_bp .id
order by
    bookings.id asc


Expected Output:
41-42
43-44
null-58
83-84
91-null


It's difficult to understand your question...
Please share the input tables data and explain exact requirements @Rakhi

What you exactly want ? (odd-even) format ?

It's great that you added output and expected output. Now add a description of what you are trying to achieve, and you will have an answer in no time. Without, everybody gets a headache :D . Good luck!

Just curious as to what happened to 41-41, 42-42,58-58, 83-83,91-91 & from where thus null came?

This may be one type of passenger pair seat arrangement. Some are booked (not-null),  some are not (NULL). @AbdullaNilam

After lots of experiments, I ultimately found the solution.
Here I'm using your data table T as:

Then separate data of the tables in three conditions as follows:
Case-I:   (departure, return_id) ≡ (departure, departure+1) & departure is Odd
Case-II:  (departure, return_id) ≡ (Not Available, return_id is Even)
Case-III: (departure, return_id) ≡ (departure is Odd, Not Available)

So, output of three cases is:

At the end join these three Cases with SQL Set Difference & Union condition
SQL Query:
with T_validBoth AS (
  select * from T
  where ((departure + 1) = return_id) and (departure % 2 = 1)
  order by departure, return_id
),
T_validRight AS (
  select NULL as departure, return_id from T
  where (departure = return_id) and (return_id % 2 = 0)
  order by departure, return_id
),
T_validLeft AS (
  select departure, NULL as return_id from T
  where (departure = return_id) and (return_id % 2 = 1)
  order by departure, return_id
),
T_Final AS (
    select * from T_validBoth 
    union
    select * from T_validRight
        where return_id NOT in (select return_id from T_validBoth)
    union 
    select * from T_validLeft
        where departure NOT in (select departure from T_validBoth)
)
select *, 
  concat(COALESCE(departure, 'null'), '-', COALESCE(return_id, 'null')) as result 
from T_Final
order by COALESCE(departure, return_id)

Sample Code: db<>fiddle
Output:

I hope it will resolve the issue ..
Wow, It's an excellent question....
I really like it ...

If someone give negative voting, that is not an issue. Please explain what I'm doing wrong ..

Somebody had a bad day.

However, the question, the purpose of which is almost impossible to understand, received 2 positive votes. Sometimes I don't understand this community.
